# a dns server acts as a caching server and authoritative server at the same time

Tags: dns, cache, bind

a dns name server acts as a caching server(recursion yes) and authoritative  server(has zone file of "example.com" zone) at the same time,if i query this name server for resource record about "host.example.com",what will happen?
A).the server asks the root zone-->com zone> example.com zone 
B).the server checks its zone file and respond according to this zone file

In a simple word,which one takes precedence?

and another similar question is which one takes precedence between the zone file and dns cache?

Comment: Not definite, but it would sure seem inefficient not to look at the domains the DNS server controls first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server with recursion enabled, will check its own zones before either [Recursively](http://techgenix.com/Understanding-DNS-Recursion/) querying or [Forwarding](http://social.dnsmadeeasy.com/blog/understanding-dns-forwarding/) to another server (forwarding is another way to pass queries on to another server).

If the DNS server did not check the local zones they are authoritative on, Recursive queries would loop infinitely, because the query would just loop back to your DNS server (cause its the authoritative server for that domain).

Note, recursion has nothing to do with caching. Some DNS servers implement caching to speed retrieval of frequently or recently queried domains, but that is not integral to how the recursive query process works.

Here is how recursion works. The three red arrows occur in order from top to bottom. ask root for where .com is, then ask .com for where contoso.com is, then ask contoso.com where example.contoso.com is, and route that answer back to the client.

[image: DNS Recursion]

One particular note, is that we are dealing with Root and gTLD servers here, and they have a special place in the global Internet ecosystem. They do not allow recursion, because the load on them would be immense.

As a result, in the image above, the client is requesting a single query from the local DNS server, which decides it will handle the request recursively (it will do all the footwork of resolving the address and send back a single response). The server then iteratively queries the Root and the gTLD server. The dns.contoso.com server itself may enable recursion however, so it may be able to supply answers to other subdomains of contoso.com like example1.example.contoso.com (authoritative on dns.example.contoso.com), with no additional queries by the clients local DNS server.

Comment: On the other hand, caching is useless without recursion, as local zones are in local memory anyway... So while it's not an integral part of recursive queries, AFAIK it is almost universally present in a resolver.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing it, but I don't see a difference in applicability of cache between iterative querying vs recursive. The only question is whether the client is sending the multiple successive requests, or the server is. In fact, for a single client with a direct Internet connection, an OS-supplied DNS cache would be the fastest performing, since you don't need to worry about sharing the cache with other systems on your LAN (since you don't have one). cache is best when it is as close to the group of clients as possible. Cache is good if you need it, but not always applicable.

Comment: Yes, I probably have my terminology mixed up.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.I have another question which is a little strange:I build a small lab which consists of a name server1 for example.com domain and another name server2 for sub.example.com which is the subdomain of example.com.then i execute "dig @server1 sub.example.com" and then i dump the cache of server1,the cache has some resource records of root name servers.In my opinion,server1 already has resource record for sub.example.com,so it does not need to check root zone.but the cache really puzzle me.

Comment: the question is, how does server1 know that server2 is authoritative for the subdomain? short answer is, it doesn't. you request brings into the equation another wrinkle; public vs private. In this case, root is the only server it knows to check for non-local domains. I'm not actually certain what setting you use on Server1 to tell it that Server2 exists, serving sub-domains. you could forward, but that would breakdown as soon as you needed Server3 and Server4. I believe that the simplest answer to your question is hosting multiple zones on Server1, but there has to be a better way. Sorry.